# Lattice MachXO3 - what's "HW Default Mode"?

Tags: fpga, lattice

What's the meaning of the "HW Default Mode" for a Lattice MachXO3 device? I've seen this term come up a few times in the configuration guide but there is no clear definition of it. Does this refer to erased/blank devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note:
> To 'Check Device ID' over the I2C configuration port, the
> MachXO3 must be in Feature Row HW Default Mode state
> (that is, blank/erased)

FPGA-TN-02055-2.7 page 49. So, you guessed right. It applies to unprogrammed or erased devices.